# Diferença entre os protocolos TLS e SSL

Tags: envio-de-email, ssl

Estou implementando uma classe para envio de emails em Android.

E estou implementando de modo que possa suportar a maioria dos serviços de e-mail. Ex: Gmail, Live, Yahoo, E e-mails de domínio próprio (Ex: meunome@meudomino.com).

> Então estou enfrentando problemas em relação a alguns provedores usarem **SSL (Secure Sockets Layer)** e outros **TLS (Transport Layer Security)**. Não sei claramente o que é, para que serve e qual a diferença entre eles. E gostaria de entender melhor isso de cada um deles. Para poder encontrar uma melhor solução ao meu problema.

### Exemplo do que estou falando

O Live (smtp.live.com:587), não aceita SSL só aceita TLS.

Já os demais que eu testei (Gmail (smtp.gmail.com:465) e Yahoo (smtp.mail.yahoo.com:465)), aceitam SSL, (Obs: se eu configurar SSL e TLS, também funciona nesse caso).

> Gostaria de entender essas diferenças, para deixar a configuração de um e-mail o mais simples possível ao usuário. E ao mesmo tempo quero suporta o maior numero de provedores de e-mail.

Hoje estou pedindo na configuração do usuário apenas:

- Host SMTP;
- Porta SMTP;
- Username (e-mail);
- Senha;
- E se o provedor exige SSL ou não;

Sei que esse assunto de protocolo é amplo e é utilizado não só em provedores de e-mail, mais também em outros tipos de comunicação de rede (como TCP, HTTP, HTTPS(com SSL)), então gostaria de manter o foco apenas no âmbito de envios de e-mails.

Obs: Gostaria de um esclarecimento apenas sobre os protocolos, não sobre a implementação, só citei no que estou utilizando no intuito de ser mais claro.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Cara, resumidamente o protocolo TLS é uma evolução do SSL. Como é possível retirar [dessa aula sobre TLS e SSL da UFRJ](http://www.gta.ufrj.br/grad/11_1/tls/):

> As diferenças entre o SSL e o TLS são muito pequenas e técnicas, porém eles possuem normas diferentes. O TLS tem a capacidade de trabalhar em portas diferentes e usa algoritmos de criptografia mais fortes como o *keyed-Hashing for Message Authentication Code* (HMAC) enquanto o SSL apenas Message Authentication Code (MAC). Além do que, a versão 1.0 do TLS não interopera com a versão 3.0 do SSL.
>
> O TLS pode ser utilizado por uma autoridade intermediária, não sendo sempre necessário recorrer à raiz de uma Autoridade de Certificação.
>
> O protocolo TLS foi criado como o sucessor do SSL. É mais freqüentemente usado como uma configuração nos programas de e-mail, mas assim como o SSL, o TLS pode ter um papel em qualquer transação cliente-servidor.

Basicamente, a tendência é que todos os servidores de e-mail migrem para o protocolo TLS, já que ele é mais atual e tem atualizações, o que não acontecerá com o protocolo SSL.

Comment: Muito bom o artigo da UFRJ, me esclareceu algumas duvidas. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: Percebi que no meu caso de configuração de e-mail, devo criar uma opção para selecionar o protocolo de segurança utilizado, algo similar a isso: **SSL, TLS, ou nenhum**. Assim no momento da configuração, o usuário deve informar qual protocolo de segurança seu provedor de e-mails utiliza, ou nenhum se não utilizar.