# Enviar e-Mail com STARTTLS porta 587

Tags: java, android, javamail

Preciso enviar um e-mail usando as configurações do cliente. O acesso ao host utiliza segurança STARTTLS usando porta 587.

Para testes montei o seguinte código (alterei os dados do cliente por segurança):

```
try {           
        String host = "200.201.202.203";
        String port = "587";
        String address = "ponto@meucliente.com.br";
        String pass = "xxxx";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", address); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port); 

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(address));

        Multipart multiPart=new MimeMultipart();

        InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress("meuemail@gmail.com"); 
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);

        message.setSubject("Send Auto-Mail"); 
        message.setContent(multiPart); 
        message.setText("Demo For Sending Mail in Android Automatically");

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, address, pass);

        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

        return true;            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```

Porém ao tentar conectar no host (transport.connect()) ocorre o seguinte erro:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
>     nested exception is:
>       javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Creio que seja alguma propriedade que falte setar (ou não), porém não sei ao certo como tratar esse erro. O que fazer nesse caso?

Fiz o mesmo teste usando a lib javamail porém obtive o mesmo erro:
https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente trocar isso

```
 props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtpserver");
```

pelo smtp do seu cliente, pois o smtp do seu cliente não deve ser smtpserver certo?

Ex:

```
     props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.meucliente.com.br");
```

Comment: Refiz a classe de envio de e-Mail, e setando a propriedade acima funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 2):

Comparando aqui com um meu, configurado com **JavaMail** que está funcionando perfeitamente a algum tempo, para **TLS**, as propriedades que tem de diferentes são:

No meu tem:

```java
props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
```

e não tem:

```java
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtpserver");
```

Acredito que esse `mail.smtp.ssl.trust` não seja uma propriedade utilizado para **TLS**, já que parece explicitamente ser uma configuração para servidores **SSL**.

Na [Documentação do JavaMail](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) diz o seguinte sobre o uso da propriedade `mail.smtp.ssl.trust`:

> If set, and a socket factory hasn't been specified, enables use of a MailSSLSocketFactory. If set to "*", all hosts are trusted. If set to a whitespace separated list of hosts, those hosts are trusted. Otherwise, trust depends on the certificate the server presents.

Que resumidamente informa que essa propriedade define o `smtp` especificado com "confiável", dispensando o uso do certificado de segurança com especificado.

> Não tenho certeza, mas parece trazer vulnerabilidade a implementação, já que você esta usando um `smtp` com certificados de segurança e ignorando isso (é necessário também observar se essa propriedade não vai ocasionar o aumento na probabilidade de seu email ser marcado com `span` por alguns servidores de email).

Tente as alterações que sugeri e veja se funciona.

Recomendo observar [esse post sobre a diferença entre **SSL** e **TLS**.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9216/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-os-protocolos-tls-e-ssl)

Comment: Grande Fernando, ótima resposta. Fiz a alteração nas propriedades, e fazendo um teste com meu email da kinghost, o qual usa TLS também, funcionou. A ÚNICA DIFERENÇA é que o meu host é "smtp.dominio" e o do cliente é "mail.dominio". Por ser "mail" preciso declarar isso na propridade? Como?

Comment: @felipearon, qual propriedade você quer declarar esse "mail.dominio" ou "smtp.dominio"? não entendi sua duvida? No "mail.transport.protocol"? Se for acredito que não faça diferença, pode permanecer `smtp`.

Comment: foi uma dúvida mesmo se precisa ou não declarar "mail" ou "smtp". Pelo que vi basta permanecer "smtp". Modo de inicialização HELO faz alguma diferença na conexão?

Comment: @felipearon, o que vem a ser HELO?

Comment: as coisas estão clareando mais. Pelo que estou entendendo, o servidor do cliente é local na empresa. Esse usa criptografia TLS com um **certificado** que não é padrão, por conta disso não estou conseguindo a conexão, diferente do certificado da kinghost (o qual fiz o teste de envio e está funcionando).

Answer (score 1):

A primeira resposta do **@user2227682** funciona perfeitamente, porém como você está utilizando Start TLS existe uma propriedade mais específica para isso, confome o **@Fernando Leal** disse, não é a regra ideal, embora funcione.

Se você quiser utilizar a propriedade abaixo também, irá funcionar perfeitamente:

```
session.getProperties().put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Portanto, as duas regras isoladas ou juntas resolvem esse tipo de problema.

---

#### Referência (em inglês):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48096615/5626568