# Segurança em PHP

Tags: php

Sou novato em segurança em php e gostaria de saber se os itens listados abaixo, ajudaria a deixar o meu site mais seguro.

1. **SSL(Secure Socket Layer)**
2. **PHP**

1. Remover toda informação possível referenciando o servidor(PHP e apache).
2. Usar sempre que possível a versão mais atual do PHP.
3. Tratar todo erro.
4. Nunca exibir algum erro do MySQL, PHP e servidor.
5. Evitar o roubo de sessão e cookie.
6. Higienizar toda entrada.

**Ofuscar**

JavaScript

JSON

Comment: Com relação a SSL, tem [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9216/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-os-protocolos-tls-e-ssl) que talvez te ajude.

Comment: JavaScript e json não vejo diferença, 'ofuscar' depende do processo. Creio que a versão estável seja mais importante que a ultima versão 'bugada'. Evitar o roubo de sessão e cookie é óbvio. Higienizar *toda* entrada não é necessário, *validar* entradas é fundamental.

Comment: Ofuscar não adiciona segurança. Utilize um programa como o `w3af` para auditar seu site. Ele vai encontrar mais erros do que você poderia visualmente.

Comment: Se for segurança contra alguém espionar dados entre o cliente e o servidor, SSL. Se for segurança contra invasão do servidor, entram os itens do PHP.  Ofuscamento é "segurança" para dificultar um pouquinho que alguém copie o código Javascript da página.

Comment: Atrapalhar a segurança não irá...

Answer (score 1):

Interessante, mas tais medidas seria você quem iria implementar na solução?

Todas essas medidas são válidas mas acrescentaria também:

- Utilização de token para envio de formulários.
- Validação de formulários em client-side e server-side.
- Definições de ACL.

Enfim, existem vários outros fatores que ajudariam pra segurança.

Não estou entrando em detalhes com relação ao tempo e dificuldade, algumas dessas coisas demoram.

Comment: Ainda continuo fazendo a implantação, valeu pela dicas